# blank form in second TabPage in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

hello I have a problem with TabControl. When I open the second Form it is always empty with no controls or anything.
my code. When I open the first tabpage everything is fine. Everything is in place

```
 private void ShowFormInTabPage(TabPage tp , Form frm)
        {
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tp);
            
            frm.TopLevel = false;
            tp.Text = frm.Text;
            frm.Visible = true;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(frm);
        }
```

I add form to tabcontrol through such a method. the methods are the same in both cases

```
private void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         _tpEmployees = new TabPage();
         if (EmployeesForm.IsNull)
         {
             ShowFormInTabPage(_tpEmployees , EmployeesForm.Instance);
             
         }
         else
         {
            

             tabControl1.SelectedTab = _tpEmployees;
        
         }
```

Comment: You're always adding the form to the first tab (i.e., `TabPages[0]`). If that's not the (only) problem, please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem, I am a novice programmer and I have such problems sometimes.